# How to restrict recognition of particular target in each particular iOS device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, vuforia

We are working in cloud recognition. In this, we have to restrict recognition of the particular image target not more than 2 recognitions in each device.

We know, we have to use VWS API for that. But our question is how we can restrict recognition of image target only in particular device, but it has to recognize in other devices which is not exceeding 2 recognitions.

How we can achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  I think you would have to keep track of the reco count separately with your own software/server, and could ignore when there are cloud recos returned on other devices, but I think the cloud would still end up recognizing the target on the other devices.

Comment: I think it's possible. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was impossible, but then after updating to Vuforia 4, I noticed in their prefab scripts they have this function `RequireComponent` now this has a lot of interesting applications to deal with.

Vuforia basically uses it to make sure the device has a camera, so you can notice that in their prefab scripts you can see `RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))`

With respect to your problem you could do something like `RequireComponent(iPhone)` because while playing with it, I noticed that was an option they gave me for the brackets.

Check it out and let us all know. I haven't been able to try it out, so can't confirm the same.